# JavaScript: Alternative to JQuery's (dual) Slider control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using the JQuery Slider control for use as a **double sided slider (dual slider)**.

It's a great UI control but I'm looking for an alternative that isn't so "fat".

Right now, just for me to use the Slider control, I have to include:

- JQuery core
- JQuery UI core
- JQuery Slider plugin

When I both minimize using Google's awesome Closure (minimizer) and GZIP the JavaScript, I'm still at around **29kb**.

*Question:* Do any comparable (dual) Slider control exist that isn't such a large download?

Answer (score 4):

How about

[jQuery Slider plugin (Safari style)](http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2010/03/jquery-slider-update/)

But to be honest 29kb isn't fat is it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative that I found today so I thought I'd share it! I haven't used it, and I don't know how heavy it is, but the folks that built it seem to have a very strong focus on accessibility, which may or may not be important for your project.

http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/misc/samples/aria/slider/doubleslider.html

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: Source code is still available, however, at: http://files.paciellogroup.com/blogmisc/samples/aria/slider/tpgSlider_source.zip